# Transforming a 'repetitive' 2D-array into a matrix using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, transformation

I have a text file that includes information in the form of:

```
A  0
B  1
C  4
D  0
E  1
A  0
B  0
C  2
D  1
E  1
A  1
B  0
C  2
D  0
E  0
...
```

Note that the total number of ABCDE cycles (here only 3 shown) is not known without counting them. 
I would like, using Python, to transform this into a matrix that has the form:

```
A  0 0 1 ...
B  1 0 0 ...
C  4 2 2 ...
D  0 1 0 ...
E  1 1 0 ...
```

I am not sure what is the best way to do such kind of transformation, does anyone as a python script that does this? Are there any function in Numpy or Pandas that would enable to do this easily? Or should I instead do it without Numpy or Pandas?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""
A  0
B  1
C  4
D  0
E  1
A  0
B  0
C  2
D  1
E  1
A  1
B  0
C  2
D  0
E  0"""
#after testing replace StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", header=None)
```

```
print (df)
    0  1
0   A  0
1   B  1
2   C  4
3   D  0
4   E  1
5   A  0
6   B  0
7   C  2
8   D  1
9   E  1
10  A  1
11  B  0
12  C  2
13  D  0
14  E  0
```

```
df = pd.pivot(index=df[0], columns=df.groupby(0).cumcount(), values=df[1])
print (df)
   0  1  2
0         
A  0  0  1
B  1  0  0
C  4  2  2
D  0  1  0
E  1  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

***option 1***
add an index level and `unstack`

```
s.index = [s.index, np.arange(len(s)) // 5]
s.unstack()
```

[image]

***option 2***
reconstruct

```
pd.DataFrame(s.values.reshape(5, -1), s.index[:5])
```

[image]

---

***setup***
I assumed a series with an index as the first column.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

txt = """A  0
B  1
C  4
D  0
E  1
A  0
B  0
C  2
D  1
E  1
A  1
B  0
C  2
D  0
E  0"""
s = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+", header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For this particular I have a preference for @jezrael solution as I do not have to specify the number of rows in the matrix, but it is great to have some alternative methods just in case.